# How does Postman send a file via HTTP?

Tags: http, web, postman

I am really curious about how Postman sends a file via `multipart/form-data` HTTP request type.

I'm unable to track the algorithm that is used to compress the file, it won't show the complete request when trying to get the request code.

I'm interested in JavaScript/React (fetch) approach.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It creates new `FormData` instance and appends `upload` as key and full path `/home/light/Downloads/helixnebula.jpg` to it as a value. Postman UI:
[image]

Comment: @Ray please click on the mentioned link in Postman and choose a `JavaScript/jQuery/AJAX` template